# Get a reference to parent method from within a method called as a parameter default

Tags: python

Python: For complicated reasons, I'd like to get a reference to the parent method from within a 'child' function called as a default value to one of the parent's parameters.

The child function will be called from a variety of parents.

To illustrate:

```
def parent(a_param = child()):
    ...

def child():
   # Somehow acquire a reference to parent here.
```

Is there a way to do this, other than just passing parent in as an argument to child?

I tried looking at the frames using inspect, but from that point of view the outer frame is just the module.

Comment: The `parent` function *doesn't even exist yet* at the time its default arguments are being evaluated, so it's impossible to get a reference to it.

Comment: Even if you _can_ somehow pull a reference out of the stack frames: ***don't.*** Make passing of data and references *explicit*, not behind-the-scenes-magic.

Comment: "other than just passing parent in as an argument to child" why do you *not* want to do this that way? That is the *reasonable* way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This gives you the name of your caller, but not a reference to it.

---

This should do it (without paying any attention to tricky cases):

```
import traceback

def f():
    parent = traceback.format_stack()[0].split('\n')[1].strip()
    return parent
   
def g(x=f()):     
    return q

def h(y=g()):
    return x
```

We look at the traceback and get the topmost element. Both `g()` and `h()` return `def g(x=f()):`, from which you can extract `g`.

Comment: Not that you should ever really do this in production for anything other than debugging or poking around. This adds too much implicit magic and will break in any number of cases which aren't exactly as you expect.

Comment: Yes agreed. Just for fun.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Your `f` function *returns a `str` object, not a reference to the method

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh you're right. I interpreted 'reference' in the informal sense. I thought sneakily knowing your caller was weird but I didn't imagine you'd want to call them (or something like that) too.